# Fatal Exception: NSObjectInaccessibleException CoreData could not fulfill a fault

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Some times application crashes while it tries to merge a secondary thread MOC to main thread MOC. Especially crashes while merging the deleted object to the main thread object.

This is my merging code in app delegate:

```
- (void)syncDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
                [self.managedObjectContext
                 mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
    } else {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(syncDidSave:) 
             withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

I have attached couple of screenshots which will show the stack trace.

Main Thread img; http://i41.tinypic.com/30047qx.png

Secondary Thread: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24ql27p&s=5

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you creating and deleting the object on the secondary thread before your main thread has any knowledge of it? If so this will cause a crash. CoreData doesn't like it when a secondary thread MOC notifies the first saying "please delete the object with this ID" but the object with that ID doesn't exist in the first MOC thread. You would think it could just ignore this case by default, but perhaps there is a good reason for not doing so and crashing instead :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The scenario is the events will added to the DB anywhere from the app. Event manager will get notified using **fetch result controller delegates** then perform's an operation based on the event type, Once the operation is done then it will go for deleting that particular events. In this was you can queue list of events it will process one by one.

Comment: I have the same problem - have you a solution, already?? Thank you in advance.